# Division between two columns with unequal lengths in two data frames

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, division

I have the following two data frames:
df1

| Item | Number | Weight |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 2 | 25 |
| B | 3 | 15 |
| B | NA | 20 |
| C | NA | 10 |

df2

| Item | Average_Weight |
| --- | --- |
| A | 12.5 |
| B | 5 |
| C | 10 |

For items in df1 where Number is NA, I'd like to estimate the Number by dividing the Weight in df1 by the Average_Weight of the Item in df2. The estimated Number will then replace the NA in df1.

The result will be the following:
df1

| Item | Number | Weight |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 2 | 25 |
| B | 3 | 15 |
| B | 4 | 20 |
| C | 1 | 10 |

Thanks for any help you can provide!

Answer (score 0):

You can join the datasets and mutate `Number`  in a second step.

**Code**

```
df1 %>% 
  left_join(df2, by = "Item") %>%
  mutate(Number = ifelse(is.na(Number), Weight/Average_Weight, Number)) %>%
  select(-Average_Weight)

  Item Number Weight
1    A      2     25
2    B      3     15
3    B      4     20
4    C      1     10
```

**Data**

```
df1 <- structure(list(Item = structure(c(1L, 2L, 2L, 3L), .Label = c("A", 
"B", "C"), class = "factor"), Number = c(2L, 3L, NA, NA), Weight = c(25L, 
15L, 20L, 10L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))

df2 <- structure(list(Item = structure(1:3, .Label = c("A", "B", "C"
), class = "factor"), Average_Weight = c(12.5, 5, 10)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```

Comment: Works! Thanks tamtam